# hamburger menu toogle closing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to find the way out of the next problem, I want that when someone clicks on the hamburger menu it opens, and then when they select something in the menu and move to that point in the page (it's a landing page) it closes automatically. At the moment it opens and works fine, just it does not close after the event. Thank you! Here is my code:

HTML:

```js
const btnHamburger = document.querySelector('#btnHamburger');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const header = document.querySelector('.header');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const fadeElems = document.querySelectorAll('.has-fade');

btnHamburger.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('click hamburger');

  if(header.classList.contains('open')){
    body.classList.remove('noscroll');
    header.classList.remove('open');    
    fadeElems.forEach(function(element){
      element.classList.remove('fade-in');
      element.classList.add('fade-out');
    });
    
  }
  else { // Open Hamburger Menu
    body.classList.add('noscroll');
    header.classList.add('open');
    fadeElems.forEach(function(element){
      element.classList.remove('fade-out');
      element.classList.add('fade-in');
    });

  }  
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header.open .header__toggle > span:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header.open .header__toggle > span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.header.open .header__toggle > span:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2d314d), to(transparent));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#2d314d, transparent);
}

.header nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 1.0625rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.0625rem;
}

.header__logo img {
  width: 12.9125rem;
  height: 4.575rem;
}

.header__toggle > span {
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #2d314d;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 3px 1px;
          transform-origin: 3px 1px;
}

.header__toggle > span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header__menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 3rem);
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.625rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header__menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  color: #2d314d;
  text-align: center;
}

.header__links a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #9698a6;
  -webkit-transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.header__links a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.header__links a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -30px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#265fd9), to(#64d9f7));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #265fd9, #64d9f7);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.header__links a:hover {
  color: #2d314d;
}

.header__links a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a name="header" id="header"></a> 
  <header class="header">
    <div class="has-fade"></div>

    <nav class="container container--pall flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
      <a href="/" class="header__logo">
        <img src="./images/img.png" alt="A" />
      </a>

      <a id="btnHamburger" href="#" class="header__toggle hide-for-desktop">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </a>

      <div class="header__links hide-for-mobile">
        <a href="#text">Text</a><a href="#text">Text</a><a href="#text">Text</a
        ><a href="#">text</a><a href="text">Text</a>
      </div>

      <a href="/" class="button header__cta hide-for-mobile"
        >Email</a>
        <a href="/" class="button header__cta hide-for-mobile"
        >011</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="header__menu has-fade">
      <a href="/">index 1</a>
      <a href="#feature">index 2</a>
      <a href="#articles">index 3</a>
      <a href="">index 4</a>
      <a href="">index 5</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: you should handle it by your self , using an event , when user clicks outside the menu or user is loosing focus on menu , event calls and it will be closed.

Comment: something like this @John?

function show(){
    mainMenu.style.display = 'flex';
    mainMenu.style.top = '0';
}
function close(){
    mainMenu.style.top = '-100%';
}

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,
select the container that holds you the item list by it's class and add event listener so when ever you clicked on of the menu we do

1. hide menu
2. hide overlay the background
3. and change back the hamburger menu to the original 3 lines
4. and remove no scroll form the body

and here is the code

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".header__menu");

// then add event listener 
container.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header.classList.remove("open");
  overlay.classList.remove("fade-in");
  container.classList.add("fade-out");
  body.classList.remove("noscroll");
});
```